# Explanation for aggregate and cbind function

Tags: r

first I can't understand aggregate function and cbind I need explanation really simple words, second I have data

```
permno number         mean        std
1   10107    120 0.0117174000 0.06802718
2   11850    120 0.0024398083 0.04594591
3   12060    120 0.0005072167 0.08544500
4   12490    120 0.0063569167 0.05325215
5   14593    120 0.0200060583 0.08865493
6   19561    120 0.0154743500 0.07771348
7   25785    120 0.0184815583 0.16510082
8   27983    120 0.0025951333 0.09538822
9   55976    120 0.0092889000 0.04812975
10  59328    120 0.0098526167 0.07135423
```

I NEED TO process this by

```
data_processed2 <- aggregate(cbind(return)~permno, Data_summary, median)
```

I cant understand this command please explain me very simple THANK YOU!

Comment: 1) `return` is not a column of your example dataset. 2) `cbind(return)` does nothing, it cbinds just one column. 3) What is `Data_summary`, where is it defined?

Comment: If you're saying you need help understanding the line of code you're using, where did it come from?

Comment: thank you everyone now I understood why it wasnt working  
                                                                                                      data_processed2 <- aggregate(cbind(return)~permno, Data_summary, median)
 now working )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cbind` takes two or more tables (dataframes), puts them side by side, and then makes them into one big table. So for example, if you have one table with columns A, B and C, and another with column D and E, after you `cbind` them, you'll have one table with five columns: A, B, C, D and E. for the rows, cbind assumes all tables are in the same order.
As noted by Rui, in your example cbind doesn't do anything, because `return` is not a table, and even if it was, it's only one thing.

`aggregate` takes a table, divides it by some variable, and the calculates a statistic on a variable within each group. For example, if I have data for sales by month and day of month, I can aggregate by month, and calculate the average sales per day for each of the months.

The command you provided uses the following syntax:

```
aggregate(VARIABLES~GROUPING, DATA, FUNCTION)
```

Variables (`cbind(return)` - which doesn't make sense, really) is the list of all the variables for which your statistic will be calculated
Grouping (`pernmo`) is the variable by which you will break the data into groups (in the sample data you provided each row has a unique number for this variable, so that doesn't really make sense either).
Data is the dataframe you're using.
Function is median.

So this call will break Data_summery into groups that have the same `pernmo`, and calculate the median for each of the columns.

With the data you provided, you'll basically get the same table back, since you're grouping the data by groups of one row each... -- Actually, since your variables are an empty group, as far as I can tell, you'll get nothing back.